# Constraint for covering all shifts

Tags: optaplanner

In a simple rostering problem, I want OptaPlanner to return "holes" in my schedule so certain shifts are uncovered if no employees are available with the required skill.

Assume 3 basic classes and that I want to penalize uncovered shifts only with `HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_SOFT`.

How do I write such a constraint?

**Employee.java**

```java
public class Employee {

    private long id = 0L;

    private List<Skill> skills;
```

**Shift.java**

```java
@PlanningEntity
public class Shift {

    private RequiredSkills

    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "employeeRange")
    private Employee employee;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX")
    private OffsetDateTime start;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX")
    private OffsetDateTime end;
```

**Schedule.java**

```java
@PlanningSolution
public class Schedule {

    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    private List<Shift> shifts;

    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "employeeRange")
    private List<Employee> employees;
```

Assume further a simple `ConstraintProvider`

```java
public class ScheduleConstraints implements ConstraintProvider {

    @Override
    public Constraint[] defineConstraints(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {

        return new Constraint[]{
            requiredSkill(constraintFactory),
        };
    }

    private Constraint requiredSkill(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.from(Shift.class)
                .filter(shift -> {
                    return !shift.getEmployee().hasSkills(shift.getSkills());
                }).penalize("Required skill", HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_HARD);
    }
```

Here is my attempt. Is it good?

```java
private Constraint allShiftsMustBeCovered(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.fromUnfiltered(Shift.class)
                .filter(shift-> {
                    return shift.getEmployee().getId() == 0L;
                }).penalize("All shifts must be covered", HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_SOFT);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, your code will throw `NullPointerException`s. If a shift is not covered, `Shift.employee` is `null`. Your constraints assume that `Employee` is never `null` - you'll have to fix that, perhaps like this:

```
// I added a null check as from() only excludes uninitialized entities.
// If employee is nullable, from() will still return Shifts with null employees.
private Constraint requiredSkill(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.from(Shift.class)
            .filter(shift -> shift.getEmployee() != null)
            .filter(shift -> {
                return !shift.getEmployee().hasSkills(shift.getSkills());
            }).penalize("Required skill", HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_HARD);
}

private Constraint allShiftsMustBeCovered(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.fromUnfiltered(Shift.class)
            .filter(shift-> shift.getEmployee() == null || 
                shift.getEmployee().getId() == 0L
            ).penalize("All shifts must be covered", HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_SOFT);
}
```

As `null` is a valid value here, make sure that `Shift.employee` [variable is nullable](https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.38.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#nullablePlanningVariable). This approach is known in the docs as **overconstrained planning**.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I want to allow shift not to be covered. I apologise if that was not clear.. I just want a `ONE_SOFT` penalty if it is uncovered. The idea is that we can always book substitutes but it costs money.

Answer (score 0):

I use a "fake employee" for that. Allow the fake employee to work any shift, but penalize those shifts so a real employee is always chosen before the fake one.